# localhost:8888/ downloads a file

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to learn node.js. I made a http server:

```
 http.createServer(function(request, response) {
  response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "test/html"});
  response.write("Hello World");
  response.end();
  }).listen(8888);
```

When I go to localhost:8888/, the page suppose to say "Hello World" but instead, a files download that has "Hello World" in it. Is this what is suppose to happen?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like you have set the Content-Type to `test/html` rather than `text/html`.  Your browser doesn't know how to handle `test/html` so it gives you the option to download the file.

Answer (score 3):

Is that "test/html" correct? Maybe could be text/html

```
response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "test/html"});
```

Answer (score 1):

you have the wrong content type `"test/html"` I will let you figure out the right answer :)

Answer (score -1):

Use

> text/plain

instead of

> text/html